# Parent selector doesn't working when using scss

Tags: sass

literally, parent selector doesn't work when using scss. This looks like the correct syntax, but why doesn't it work? If anyone knows please help me.

```css
div {
  h1 {
    background: $green;
    color: white;
  }
  &.title {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: purple;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the compiled code look like?

Comment: @Arkellys I'm using webpack 5 and the code file "webpack.dev.js".
I think the github address will be more convenient, so I'll leave a link
github: [my github link](https://github.com/jungjuyoung/webpack-boilerplate/tree/main/config)